# How to specify the c++ version in gradle?

Tags: c++, gradle

I just started to learn Gradle. I don't know how to set the language standard. I use gradle + CLion.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_cpp_projects.html

Comment: My recommendation: don't. CMake might be ugly but it is not as defunct as Gradle for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many C++ compilers, the language standard to which it adheres is set by using a `std` compiler option.

For example, to set the standard to C++ 20 when using a Microsoft compiler, use its compiler option `/std=c++20` (on non-Windows systems, such a compiler option may appear as `-std=c++20`).

I'm not very familiar with setting compiler options on Gradle, but I think it has something to do with adding code like the following to a `build.gradle` file:

```
tasks.withType(CppCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-nowarn"]
}
```

Comment: compilerArgs.add "/std:c++latest"